# Laravel, get result like in Eloquent use Query Builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I need a little help.

I have two tables with one to may relationship.

Table1 and Table2.

When I get data use the Eloquent model, I have result like this:

```
Table1Model::with('table2Result')->get()->toArray();
```

**Output** :

```
[
    [
        'id',
        'name',
        'table2Result' => [
            [
                'id',
                'name',
                'content'
            ],
            [
                'id',
                'name',
                'content'
            ],
            ...
        ],
        ....
    ]
]
```

How I can get the same result use Query Builder?

Thanks in advance for your reply=)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
DB::table('Table1Model')
        ->join('Table2Result', function ($join) {
            $join->on('Table1Model.K', '=', 'Table2Result.FK')->orOn(...);
        })
        ->get();
```

Good luck

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. But I have the not grouped result

Comment: can you tell me more please why do need the builder in which context, then i can tell you what to do.

Comment: I want to get the same result as after using the model. So that the table2Result field contains all relationships from table 2 for the corresponding record in table 1

Comment: Eloquent model work to slow for me, so I won to use query builder for best performance

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/S5SgJdG.png

On the left part, I have results from the model. In the right part, I have results from the query builder when I use join.  I want grouped right part like left

Comment: Then make the first select and do it to array 1, and make the second select from the table with the were on the foreign key and make it array. and finally merge the 2 arrays. but then i dont beleive that this will be more performant since this is exactly what eloquent do. to have more performance you can use indexes on you table then the join will be more performant.

Comment: I have used a query with a loop as you wrote and for my dataset, the query plus loop for relationships is faster than Eloquent plus "with". Thanks for your help